# Ubuntu 14.04 Canon MG 5220 problem

Tags: 14.04

Canon MG 5220 in back room, no computer plugged in. I can print when plugged in via usb, but not wireless. My wife can print wireless with Windows 10. Wireless, I can add the printer in system settings, it appears to print on my laptop, but the printer doesn't respond. The URI when adding wireless printer is `smb://localhost/MG5200-series`. The dialog box suggests it should be an `ipp://` type address. `Printer state is Idle - Tree connect failed (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)`